# mySQL Select statement with generic incrementing value

Tags: mysql

I have an odd situation I am trying to handle. In a mySQL `SELECT` query, I need to have a field, not coming from the database, that just counts up from 0 for each record returned.

For background info, I have to query a table of addresses, which currently looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  addressID, 
  address_1, 
  address_2, 
  city, 
  state, 
  zipcode, 
  country, 
  county, 
  address_type 
FROM employee_address 
WHERE employee_id = 1234
```

Each record returned opens a new instance of a template of form fields in java, populated with the address info.

But I need a dummy field that just counts up from 0 for each record returned, that can be assigned to each template as an "index", which is used for reference later in my python coding (without this I have no index to go by at a later point in the code). Hopefully something like this

```
SELECT 
  increment(0) AS templateID, 
  addressID, 
  address_1, 
  address_2, 
  city, 
  state, 
  zipcode, 
  country, 
  county, 
  address_type 
FROM employee_address 
WHERE employee_id = 1234
```

And unfortunately I don't have access to change the java code to just give the templates an index value. Sad but true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable:

```
SELECT 
  @idx:=@idx+1 AS templateID, 
  addressID, 
  address_1, 
  address_2, 
  city, 
  state, 
  zipcode, 
  country, 
  county, 
  address_type
FROM employee_address, (SELECT @idx:=-1) AS var 
WHERE employee_id = 1234
```

`templateID` will start from 0 and then will be incremented by one for each record returned by the query.

Comment: I knew there would be something more advanced, but had no idea what to search for. Thank you Giorgos!